# Android: Prevention backup file after download

Tags: android, download

I use this code for download and save to **sdcard Download folder**

```
Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(link);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
request.setMimeType(exe);
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToExternalStorage + "file.mp3")));
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

After download completed , create backup file in **Audio** folder

How Prevention for this action?

**Note** : if delete this file from `Download` folder , remains `Audio` folder